# zsh: complete relative path as absolute?

Tags: zsh, filenames, autocomplete

I'm trying to write a completion function for a command that requires that its argument be an absolute path.  (No, I don't know why.)  I thought it would be nice to allow typing a relative path, but completion would expand it to an absolute path — that way, if I forget the requirement for an absolute path, completion will fix it for me.  For example, if my working directory is home and I have a file "foo" and I type `fo<TAB>`, it would complete to `/usr/me/foo` instead of just `foo` like `_files` would do.

Problem is, I have no idea how to do this.  I've been through all the flags on `_files` and `compadd`, and nothing sounds relevant.  `_canonical_paths` sounds close, but I can't get it to do anything.  Once the argument is an absolute path, `_files` works just fine; it's that initial step that's the issue.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

The following function prepends `$PWD/` to any relative path before passing it to `_files`, which is the normal completion function for files.

```
_absolute_files () {
  local expansion=$PREFIX$SUFFIX; expansion=${(e)expansion}
  if [[ "${expansion%%/#}" != "${expansion:a}" ]]; then
    PREFIX="\$PWD/$PREFIX"
  fi
  _files "$@";
}
```

This works in many common cases, including recognizing paths starting with `~/` and such as absolute, and with paths expressed using a variable. I haven't thought about all possible interactions with expansion (e.g. of wildcards) and with embedding.