# ZSH completion for git does not autocomplete absolute path?

Tags: zsh, git, autocomplete

I have git repository in `/.git`, ie root of my filesystem.

When I am in `/etc/foo/` and do `git status`, git tells me that file `../fstab` has changed.

When I want to use `zsh` completion for `git` command (still in /etc/foo/), ie:

```
git diff ../fs<TAB>
```

that works. But when I use absolute path, ie:

```
git diff /etc/fs<TAB>
```

then `zsh` does not complete the absolute path.

**How can I tell `zsh` to complete absolute paths, as well as relative paths ?**

I am using `zsh` version `5.7.1-1` on Debian Buster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**ZSH Completion:**

Zsh completion are done with scripts usually located at `/usr/share/zsh/5.5/functions/Completion/Unix` (may differ depending on the distro) each command completion's script is named `_commandName`, Zsh include/handle those scripts with the environment variable `$fpath` similar to the variable `$PATH`, in this case the used script is `_git`, the location order on `$fpath` is important as Zsh use the first `_git` script that it find and ignore the others if present (also similar to `$PATH`).

**Scripting:**

Like explained on this [QA](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/543549/zsh-complete-relative-path-as-absolute) and **as an example**, the following function prepends `$PWD/` to any relative path before passing it to `_files`, which is the normal completion function for files.

```
_absolute_files () {
  local expansion=$PREFIX$SUFFIX; expansion=${(e)expansion}
  if [[ "${expansion%%/#}" != "${expansion:a}" ]]; then
    PREFIX="\$PWD/$PREFIX"
  fi
  _files "$@";
}
```

This works in many common cases, including recognizing paths starting with `~/` and such as absolute...

**Solution:**

The default `git` completion behavior does not include relative paths, we could edit its script and add a function like the one on the explanation above to add support for relative path **or** we could simply replace the default `git` completion with the completion plugin `gitfast` from [ohmyzsh](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh) with the following steps:

Clone [ohmyzsh](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh) to some location (let say `/location`):

```
git clone https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh.git
```

Edit `~/.zshrc` and add at the bottom of the config file the following to include `gitfast`:

```
fpath=( /location/ohmyzsh/plugins/gitfast $fpath )
```

The order is important as explained before and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17968024/zsh-disable-default-completion-for-make).

Update the completion cache by removing any `~/.zcompdump*` then run `compinit`.

**Alternative solution:**

Editing `/usr/share/zsh/5.5/functions/Completion/Unix/_git` by applying the following patch on `_git-diff` function:

```
--- _git
+++ _git
@@ -766,6 +766,12 @@

   case $state in
     (from-to-file)
+  
+      if [[ $line[1] == *\/* ]]; then
+        _alternative 'files::_files' && ret=0
+        return ret
+      fi
+      
       # If "--" is part of $opt_args, this means it was specified before any
       # $words arguments. This means that no heads are specified in front, so
       # we need to complete *changed* files only.
```

Answer (score 3):

Zsh can complete absolute paths just fine. Just try `ls /etc/fs`<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

The problem lies with whatever `_git` completer you are using. (See footnote below.)

You can test this as follows:

1. Make sure you have initialized `compinit`:

```bsh
autoload -Uz compinit && compinit
```

2. Type `git diff` (with a space at the end) and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>, followed by the letter <kbd>H</kbd>.

I get the following output:

```bsh
tags in context :completion::complete:git-diff::
    argument-rest options  (_arguments _git-diff _git)
tags in context :completion::complete:git-diff:argument-rest:
    commit-ranges blobs-and-trees-in-treeish files blobs  (_git-diff _git) 
    heads commit-tags commit-objects                      (__git_commits __git_commit_ranges _git-diff _git) 
    heads-local heads-remote                              (__git_heads __git_commits __git_commit_ranges _git-diff _git) 
    messages                                              (_message __git_command_successful __git_heads_local __git_heads __git_commits __git_commit_ranges _git-diff _git) 
    heads-local                                           (__git_describe_branch __git_describe_commit __git_heads_local __git_heads __git_commits __git_commit_ranges _git-diff _git) 
    heads-remote                                          (__git_describe_branch __git_describe_commit __git_heads_remote __git_heads __git_commits __git_commit_ranges _git-diff _git) 
    messages                                              (_message __git_command_successful __git_tags_of_type __git_commit_tags __git_commits __git_commit_ranges _git-diff _git) 
    messages                                              (_message __git_command_successful __git_recent_commits __git_commit_objects_prefer_recent __git_commits __git_commit_ranges _git-diff _git) 
    changed-in-working-tree-files                         (__git_changed-in-working-tree_files _git-diff _git) 
    blob-tags blob-objects                                (__git_blobs _git-diff _git) 
    messages                                              (_message __git_command_successful __git_tags_of_type __git_blob_tags __git_blobs _git-diff _git)
tags in context :completion::complete:git::
    argument-rest  (_arguments _git)
```

Note that this does *not* include `files`, `directories` or `globbed-files` (which you will see when you type `ls`, followed by  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>). What it does include is `changed-in-working-tree-files`, which are generated by `git diff -z --name-only --no-color` (as you can see [here](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/014eaf7e810dda8be5eaf97c37c9f86e6e839022/Completion/Unix/Command/_git#L6888)), which produces paths that are relative to the root of the repo and not absolute paths.

Ergo, your absolute path will not get completed in the `git` context as it does not have the info there to do so.

---

Footnote: Are you using Zsh's own `_git` completer or one that might have been installed by Git? I highly recommend **not** using the one installed by Git, as it is not properly implemented by Zsh standards and thus rather buggy in certain parts. (It appears to be some kind of automatic – and flawed – port from Git's completer for Bash.) Check your `fpath` for any completer file called `_git` that doesn't belong to Zsh's installation and remove it.